# "is not included in the list" when fields_for on a one-to-many

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is on rails 2.3. I cut a bunch of code out to hopefully get to the point of the problem. When I click save on a User object with 1 or more EmailPreferences, I get

1 error prohibited this user from being saved

There were problems with the following fields:

Notification type is not included in the list

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :email_preferences
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :email_preferences
  attr_accessible :email_preferences_attributes
end

class EmailPreference < ActiveRecord::Base
  # receives is a boolean, notification_type is a string.
  attr_accessible :user_id, :receives, :notification_type
  belongs_to :user
end

class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
    @user.email_preferences.build :receives=>false, :notification_type=>"outage"
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end
end

# app/views/user/_form.rhtml
<% form_for :user, user do |f| -%>
  <% f.fields_for :email_preferences do |preference_form| -%>
    <dd>
      <%= preference_form.check_box :receives %>
      <!-- I just want to display the notification type. I do not want to edit it. -->
      <%= preference_form.object.notification_type %>
    </dd>
  <% end -%>
  <%= form_submit f.object, :cancel => companies_path %>
<% end -%>
```

*Edit*

Even better, how would you go about debugging error messages that aren't so helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, adding a hidden input does seem to work. It also looks like Rails doesn't need the hidden notification_type if the email preference is already in the database. So perhaps the rule is that for new sub-objects, you need to include all the required fields.

```
<% f.fields_for :email_preferences do |preference_form| -%>
  <dd>
    <%= preference_form.check_box :receives %>
    <!-- I just want to display the notification type. I do not want to edit it. -->
    <%= preference_form.object.name %>
    <%= preference_form.hidden_field :notification_type %>
  </dd>
<% end -%>
```